# How to apply data bound dynamic skinning for Background Color change in adf pages?

Tags: css, background-color, oracle-adf, skinning

I need to change the background color for my fusion application built using oracle ADF technology. The requirement is for a data bound solution where my colours should be stored in database, and a dropdown in the UI should be used to fetch the colors, which should accordingly change my background color of the page. Currently using Jdevelopr 11.1.2.4.0 to develop my project.

I have already followed oracle blogs like : **http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_83/jdtut_11r2_83.html**
but failed to implement it. Any help would be appreciated. 
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Skin CSS file just do the following:

```
af|document{
 background: none;
 background-color: #intended-color;
}
```